# Nextjs with Vue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, next.js

I am using Vue and now I want to use Nextjs framework for SEO and server side rendering and more benefits.

I have worked a little with React before, but I want to focus on Vue.

Can I use Nextjs with Vue 3 instead of React?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to move out from React?

Answer (score 2):

Next JS is a framework that is specifically designed for React applications. While you may be able to get Next JS to work with Vue with some hacks, it is not recommended. I'll suggest you look into Nuxt JS which is a framework that was specifically designed for Vue JS applications offering features that support server-side rendering and search engine optimisation (SEO). Here's a link to Nuxt JS's documentation for your reference.

https://nuxt.com/docs

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure that even with hacks this would be something feasible at all haha. Yeah, do not mix React and Vue together especially if server + client-side. Vue can work inside of React but the opposite is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Next brings of a higher value for server-side rendering, but you could indeed use Nuxt as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281467/8816585).
Or even consider using [Astro](https://astro.build/) + Vue, both mix well together!
(Astro is able to mix any kind of framework, like React + Vue + Svelte at the same time, while having a nice ecosystem + community + server support too)

---

Other alternatives like Vitesse and Îles are also available but those projects are really tiny and not as hugely maintained. Give it a search if you're really not happy with the Nuxt or Astro.